# How to connect 3/4 electrical conduit to existing flush mount exterior outlet

Tags: electrical

[image: Picture of exterior]

What type of gang box do I need to accomplish this.  Basically I've run electrical cable in the 3/4 conduit and need to connect it to this outlet.

Comment: How was the receptacle connected before? Is there gfci protection? I see just straight  conduit - where is the end?

Comment: You surface mounting the outlet on top of the old one?

Comment: Extension box of an appropriate type for the environment.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What's the plan for the existing outlet?  Remove?  What about the wiring that goes to it?

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @Harper, you will need a *single-gang weatherproof box extension* with 3/4" threaded port and whatever pvc fittings you need to get to and attach to the box extension.

[image]

Comment: Consider PVC fittings to enter the box from the bottom or side.  Otherwise any failure in the pipe-box connection will result in rainwater dripping down the pipe entering your house through the existing box.  Better yet, consider using the existing box and extension (above) *solely* to transition from inside to outside, then a short piece of pipe going *down* to a new external box, with an outlet and a connection for your riser.